# How to add click event on mat-row in angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I added this but when inspecting element using Chrome DevTools, the click function doesn't show!

Here's my code:

```html
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1" class="mat-table">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Objname">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ObjName </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.objname}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Successcount">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Successcount   </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.successcount}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row (click)="getRecord(element.objname)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 119):

almost the same solution as above but a bit more useful if you are trying to get the object from the clicked row

```
<mat-row  *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="getRecord(row)"></mat-row>
```

when you console log the row you will get the entire object of the row

Comment: Thanks is this documented somewhere?? I would like to know the class/type of object you get back etc etc.

Comment: how can I get the row data to another component variable?

Comment: The class/type is the type of your item. There's no need to do something like `row.data`. In fact I find it more readable to put `let customer` instead of `let row` then your event becomes `(click)="selectCustomer(customer.id)` or something like that.

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 31):

If some body needs to use a router link you can do it like bellow:

```html
<tr 
  mat-row 
  *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns" 
  [routerLink]="['/newsfeed/editnews/', element.NewsfeedID]">
</tr>
```

you should create a route to match the link, for example:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'editnews/:newsfeedid', component:NewsfeedformComponent
  }
]
```

If you want to get the id from url in your component, under ngOnInit use ActivatedRoute like bellow:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

ngOnInit() {
this._activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
// in the route we created edit route we set newsfeedid as param so we get it here
  const NewsfeedID = +params.get('newsfeedid');
  if (NewsfeedID) {
    //this.getAgentbyid(agentid);
    console.log(NewsfeedID);
    }
 })
}
```

Comment: What, if I have a mat-icon-button for additional actions in each row? How could I prevent that the router gets triggered, when clicking that icon (which should open a dropdown-menu instead?

Comment: add this in your icon: (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"

Comment: ah, perfect. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 12):

Watch your `*matRowDef`, you created a row variable, yet in your click event, you're giving an element one.

```
<mat-row (click)="getRecord(element.objname)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Otherwise, you won't see it be inspecting it : **Angular creates event listeners in JS to handle events**. You can either create it in HTML or in Javascript, they choose to do it in Javascript. Just test your function with a console log, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

In general a click event on the row works (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmb2x1?file=app/table-basic-example.html).

The `element.objname` is not defined in that scope. You have to rename `let row;` to `let element`.

Comment: <mat-row
      (click)="selectedRow(row)"
      *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
    ></mat-row>

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to add a formControl to the material table as such

```
<mat-table matSort
             [formControl]="formControl"
             ...
             >
       ....
</mat-table>
```

and then in my ngOnInit method use

```
readonly formControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe((request: RequestViewModel) => {
      this.selectedInvestigationId(request.investigation.investigationInfoId, request.speciality);
    });
  }
```

The benefits are numerous:

- It will work with keyboard navigation (formControl treats selection    with SPACE/ENTER/click equally).
- It can use form validation
- You can use form flags, such as ng-dirty

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="onRowClick(row)"></tr>
```

I'm using **Angular 14** and **Angular Material 14**. I have just passed a function in the last tr tag which is "matRowDef" row. It's returning the row value perfectly when I click over a row.