# onclick element on a mat table cell with expandable row

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

So im working on expandable MatRow tables ,but my issue is I need to add a button to each row  with a click element and open a modal on click ,But its not working

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{column}} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="getTableElement(element)" [innerHtml]="element[column] | safeHtml"></td>
        
        </ng-container>
<\table>
```

I am displaying data based on inner html and using pipe to sanitize and allow displaying of HTML elements ,But my on click function is not working

**What I have tried so far**

**Event binding to the button**

```
elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click',alert(1))
```

**Hostlistener to get clicked id**

```
@HostListener('document:click',['$event.target']) onDocumentClick(event:any){
  alert(event.id)
}
```

But nothing works ,can I know what I am doing wrong ?
any help would be greatly appreciated .

**Thanks for the answers but had a mistake in my code .corrected it**

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164039/how-to-add-click-event-on-mat-row-in-angular-material-table

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a click event directly to the button in the HTML like:

```
<button (click)="doSomething()"></button>
```

You can read more about Angular Event Binding here: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding